# finding the source codes in order to learn to program

Tags: ubuntu, libraries

I just installed ubuntu on my PC, and now I wish to browse into some code. As a starting point I wana see the GLCells screen saver source code

How/where can i find the source code of the GLCells. In general, how can i find the source codes of the ubuntul OS distribution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get build-dep xscreensaver  # Install the libraries and the tools needed
apt-get source xscreensaver          # Download the sources
cd xscreensaver-5.10
(make changes to code)
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot         # Build a .deb
sudo gdebi ../xscreensaver*.deb      # Install the package
```

To avoid having to do a full recompile after every change, follow the instructions here: http://www.debian.org/doc/maint-guide/ch-build.en.html

Comment: That first command is the most important one, and it works for any Ubuntu package. Great answer!

Answer (score 4):

GLCells is bundled with XScreenSaver, the source can be downloaded here:

http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/download.html

The Ubuntu source CD in ISO format is here (complete with [CD Burning Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto)):

http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/releases/9.10/release/source/

Answer (score 0):

How about the [ubuntu repository](http://archive.ubuntu.com/)?